# Can I charge 604050 LiPo battery using USB charger and single resistor?

Tags: usb, battery-charging, charging, lipo

The battery I got off Aliexpress has a protection chip:

[image: Aliexpress LiPo Battery with chip]

I'm wondering - **Will the chip protect the battery against overcharging if I use a standard 5V USB charger and a single resistor in series?**

[image: Schematics]

EDIT: I'm fixing a toy worth fiver. There is no room for the proper charger inside the toy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protection chip is designed to prevent the battery from lighting on fire. It won't prevent the battery from getting damaged.

Don't do this. Use a proper charger.

The protection circuit disconnects the battery when the voltage on the battery terminals gets excessively high. The trip voltage is quite a bit higher than the regular (safe) maximum voltage of the battery. The popular DW01 protection IC specifies it as up to 4.35V, while the maximum charge voltage for a LiPo is typically 4.2V. At that point, the battery *will* be damaged, but it (hopefully) won't explode or catch on fire yet.

You can get really tiny LiPo charging boards that aren't much bigger than a USB connector. Not using a proper charger is simply *not an option* - charging the battery with nothing but a resistor and 5V *will* kill the battery in almost no time. It might not even last 10 cycles if you overcharge it this way. See: https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA572554.pdf

Comment: What exactly does this chip? Does it limit the current? Does it disconnect the battery under certain conditions?

Comment: If the toy isn't worth fixing properly - with a real LiPo charger board - please just don't fix it at all. If you do what you suggested, the battery will at best be dead after charging it a few times, and at worse, the toy will start to burn.

Comment: A responsible vendor would have supplied a datasheet (or a web link to it) that describes how the battery should be properly charged.

Answer (score 1):

No.  As mentioned in another answer, the chip is just there to prevent the battery from catching on fire.  Usually they work by detecting fault conditions and permanently shutting off the battery.

You need a proper LiPo battery charger.  This basically means it'll do constant-current up to 4.2 (or so) volts, then constant voltage until the charge current goes down to some threshold, then it will *stop charging altogether*.

So you need to obtain or make a proper charging circuit.

Answer (score 1):

No. Don't do that.

The battery protection chipset, if it even monitors for overvoltage, will cut off the charging only when there already is overvoltage due to failure of the charging circuitry.

If the battery protection chipset monitors for overvoltage and disconnects the battery from the wires after there is enough overvoltage and battery has already slightly damaged, it may do so permanently and will onviously render your battery useless, because there is no point trying to use slightly damaged batteries.